# Using Angular date pipe. Is it possible to format the date within the placeholder?

Tags: html, angular, date, pipe, transform

I have a form in which the user can update a request or post that they have made and I was wanting to display the date in month/day year inside of the placeholder as that is one of the fields that the user can update.  Is this a doable thing?

```
<input type="text"
  id="needByDate"
  name="needByDate"
  id="needByDate"
  placeholder="request.needByDate"
  [(ngModel)]="request.needByDate" />
```

Comment: Your placeholder and model are the same so placeholder will never be visible anyways? It will only show the value if one exists.

Comment: You can format placeholder like this. `placeholder="{{datePlaceholder | date}}"`
If you want to format the value of the text input field that's different. There is also an actual date input field. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider implementing it as demonstrated below:

```
<input type="text"
  id="needByDate"
  name="needByDate"
  id="needByDate"
  [placeholder]="request.needByDate | date"
  [(ngModel)]="request.needByDate" />
```